# Recommendation on number of instance in BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

Are there any best practices or suggestions on how many instances one should have in BigTable ? 
What is good practice among these 2 situations ?

a) To have 2 INSTANCES with 2 clusters each

- Instance A has 2 clusters : Cluster A1 and Cluster A2 ; both are in **us-EAST1** region
- Instance B has 2 clusters : Cluster B1 and Cluster B2 ; both are in **us-EAST4** region

OR

b) To have just 1 INSTANCE with 2 clusters :

- Cluster C1  in **us-EAST1** region and
- Cluster C2 in **us-EAST4** region

I understand cluster is for replicability and both the above situations factor in replication.

To me, it looks like situation b) ( 1 Instance ) is more effective since it not only covers replication but it also covers BOTH regions, us-EAST1 and us-EAST4, and with 1 less Instance (and hence,less $$$).

Please advise on this from what you know and/or if you also have any practical experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

While each use case depends in the business needs, each replication configuration has its own leverage. I will point out some important topics to consider between these two situations.

Bigtable is a high performance scalable NoSQL database which is ideal for large analytical workloads. Regarding [Replication](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/replication-overview#consistency-model), according to the documentation it enables you to increase availability and durability. Furthermore,  it is considered to be eventually consistent, which means that when you write a change to your cluster it will be able to read the change from the other clusters in the instance just once the changes are replicated between the clusters.

- **Replication and throughput**

***Read throughput***: replication can improve read through put, specially when you use multi-cluster routing. It, also, can reduce latency if the cluster is closer to the customer's region. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#performance-read-requests).

***Write throughput***: according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#performance-write-throughput), replication does not increase write throughput. The write throughput can go down because a write to one cluster must be replicated to the other clusters. Thus, each cluster is spending more CPU resources to pull the changes from the other ones. For example:

- If the number of nodes in a cluster is doubled, a  3 nodes cluster now with 6 nodes (for example), the write throughput for the instance doubles. However, the data is only  available in one zone.
- Adding a second cluster with the same number of nodes, a cluster of 3 nodes and another one with 3 nodes, 6 nodes in total. Then, the data is available in two different zones but the write throughput might go down because each piece of data is written twice when it is replicated to the other clusters.

**Replication latency:** replicated clusters in different zones will, generally, have higher latency than clusters within the same region.

You should also consider [app profiles and traffic routing](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/performance#performance-traffic-routing) within your business needs. Multi-cluster routing minimises latency because it is an automatic choice that routes the requests to the closest cluster in a instance (from the perspective of the application) which results in the lowest latency possible. Whereas single-cluster routing can be used to separate workloads or have read-write semantics in the same cluster.

Google prepared some examples of replication use cases in order to clarify the advantages of each setting. I encourage you to have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/replication-settings).

In case you need some more architectural advice you can also contact GCP, [here](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

***UPDATE***

Analysing your 2 cases:

If you have 1 Instance with 4 clusters, it will maintain your data highly available. Also, if you have the clusters in the same region but different zones, it will increase regional resilience and the ability of fail over without generating cross-region replication costs. However, you can have only one have one App Profile (multi or single-cluster routing). That means, you won't be able to separate analytics workloads from other applications. So, when you have a to run a large batch job, it can slow things down to the application's users.

Now, if you have 2 instances with 2 clusters each. You can have high availability and even regional resilience if the clusters are in the same zone for the same instance. However, if the clusters are in different regions it will incur of replication costs from one region to another. Also, the table/data belongs to the instance. Thus, you will be able to separate analytical workloads from the other applications, which will help in performance (when running large batch jobs), each instance with its own App Profile configurations.

Comment: Hi @Alexandre, thanks for your detailed response. Really appreciate it. I understand the clustering aspect and i am not questioning. Is there a benefit to having clustering on 1 instance and 4 clusters v/s 2 instances and 2 clusters ? My more specific question was about the _Instances_ and hence, my example. Can you re-review it , please ?

Comment: Let's analyse both, If you have 1 Instance with 4 clusters, it will maintain your data highly available. Also, if you have the clusters in the same region but different zones, it will increase regional resilience and the ability of fail over without generating cross-region replication costs. However, you can have only one have one App Profile (multi or single-cluster routing). That means, you won't be able to separate analytics workloads from other applications. So, when you have a to run a large batch job, it can slow things down to the application's users.

Comment: Now, if you have 2 instances with 2 clusters each. You can have high availability and even  regional resilience if the clusters are in the same zone for the same instance. However, if the clusters are in different regions it will incur of replication costs from one region to another. Also, the table/data belongs to the instance. Thus, you will be able to separate analytical workloads from the other applications, which will help in performance (when running large batch jobs), each instance with its own App Profile configurations. Did it help you ?

Comment: Thanks. It does ! That makes a lot of sense and also helps me get some perspective from the real-life or it's application point of view.

Comment: @NikM., please do not forget to accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Hi Alex, i did upvote the above 2 answers. They were indeed very useful & answered my questions perfectly. Thanks v.much

Comment: @NikM., you need to upvote and accept the main, not the comments, when the answer helps you. As in the [guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) of stack. I have updated the answer with the two comments I made about your case.